# The exec in stored procedure doesn't work

Tags: sql-server-2008

This is in a stored procedure and doesn't work (I mean on `exec` part):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [sp_SalerTickets_AddByTemp]
    @Filter varchar(8000),
    @UserID int
AS
   if (len(@Filter) = 0)
    return

   declare @ID varchar(10)
   set @ID = convert(varchar(10), @UserID)

   exec('insert into T_ActionTicketSale(ActionTicketID, UserID)

   select ID, ' + @ID + ' 
   from V_ActionTickets 
   where ID in (select TicketID 
                from T_TmpProcessTicketAction 
                where ' + @Filter + ')')
```

The `@Filter` comes from C# code and looks like this:

```
string filter = string.Format("SessionID='{0}'", sessionId);
string sql = String.Format("exec sp_SalerTickets_AddByTemp @Filter='{0}', @UserID={1}", filter, salerID);
```

But this works:

```
insert into T_ActionTicketSale(ActionTicketID, UserID)

select ID, 2950 
from V_ActionTickets 
where ID in (select TicketID from T_TmpProcessTicketAction where SessionID = 'test')
```

I'm not sure what's going on here, because I need exec to work.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but this is functional issue.

Answer (score 1):

Let's pretend your session id is `1234`. In that case, your filter will look like:

```
SessionID='1234'
```

Therefore, your `sql` variable will look like:

```
exec sp_SalerTickets_AddByTemp @Filter='SessionID='1234'', @UserID='SomeUserId'
                                       ^          ^    ^^
```

This will be a syntax error - you are closing your @Filter string too early.

**EDIT**:

Also, please read up on SQL Injection. If either your session ID or UserId variables are under the control of a user, you are leaving yourself wide-open to a SQL Injection attack.

Comment: What do you mean by possible syntax error? What should I fix?